# rtk query ts error jwt does not exists on type

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

Why I get this error ?

```
Property 'jwt' does not exist on type '{ data: IAuthResponse; } | { error: FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError; }'.
  Property 'jwt' does not exist on type '{ data: IAuthResponse; }'.ts(2339)
```

I use RTK Query and want to handle my response:

Query.tsx

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { IAuthLoginForm } from '../../../components/Login/Model';
import { IAuthResponse } from './Model';

export interface IAuthResponse {
  jwt: string;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  profile_name: string;
}

export const AuthFlow = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'AuthFlow',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://192.168.0.249:4000/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation<IAuthResponse, IAuthLoginForm>({
      query: (form) => ({
        url: '/login',
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
      })
    })
  })
});

export const { useLoginMutation } = AuthFlow;
```

Home.tsx

```
...
const [register, { data, error, isLoading }] = useLoginMutation();

const Submit = () => {
 const response = await register('test');
 
 if(response.jwt) {
   // ERROR above jwt not exists on property
 }
};
```

Why I get this error if I want to access .jwt ? I use it in my Model..
can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the RTK Query docs:

> The "mutation trigger" is a function that when called, will fire off the mutation request for that endpoint. Calling the "mutation trigger" returns a promise with an unwrap property, which can be called to unwrap the mutation call and provide the raw response/error. This can be useful if you wish to determine whether the mutation succeeds/fails inline at the call-site.

Your mutation trigger here is the **register**, so to access the data from your response with rtk query you should use one of this approaches:

```
const Submit = async (data: IAuthLoginForm) => {
 // note the unwrap here, you always use it to get the data
 await register(data).unwrap().then((response) => {
   // Handle the response here
   console.log(response)
 });
};
```

Or use the useEffect hook to get the response data

```
const Submit = (data: IAuthLoginForm) => {
 register(data)
};

useEffect(() => {
   // use the const data to get the response
   console.log(data)
}, [data])
```

to handle errors you can call `.catch` nested to `.then` like this:

```
const Submit = async (data: IAuthLoginForm) => {
 await register(data).unwrap().then((response) => {
   // Handle the response here
   console.log(response)
 }).catch((error) => {
   // Handle the error here
   console.log(error)})
};
```

Or you can use the const error from your **useLoginMutation** inside an useEffect just like i did with the const **data**:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // use the const error to get the error
   console.log(error)
}, [error])
```

One last thing, to send the data properly to the server, the data that comes from the submit should be the same type of the data that you defined in your `builder.mutation<IAuthResponse, IAuthLoginForm>`

So you have also two approaches here:

```
const Submit = async (data: IAuthLoginForm) => {
 // send the same data type from submit and just pass to register
 await register(data).unwrap().then((response) => {
   // Handle the response here
   console.log(response)
 });
};
```

Or pass each data individually to register like so:

```
const Submit = async (data: IAuthLoginForm) => {
 // note that i used an example here because i don't know how your interface IAuthLoginForm looks like
 await register({data1: data.data1, data2: data.data2 }).unwrap().then((response) => {
   // Handle the response here
   console.log(response)
 });
};
```

Some reference about the unwrap and mutations for you: [Frequently Used Mutation Hook Return Values](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#frequently-used-mutation-hook-return-values)

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but how I handle error messages ? Maybe I can get a response JWT or I can get a Error Message. So what should I do then ?

Comment: i will edit my answer to include error handling too

Comment: Thanks but I mean, it can successfull send a response back but maybe the username have bad characters so then I give him a successfully response named: Error: 'Please enter new username', catch comes when fetch or anything fails but it not fails

Comment: There's no sense in sending a successfully response if something failed, you must check the username before sending it to server and also check it again on the server to ensure a good level of security, for instance, if the user sends a username with bad characters your api(the endpoint where you are sending and handling the username) should check it and return a response with status 400, any status between 400 and 599 is considered an error and will be treated by **.catch** and also populated in **const error**, so you can handle it, hope i clarified the things a bit.

Comment: for more information about the status codes, read this: [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: I have understand thank you very much!